# Redirecionar usuários através de um formulário

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso criar uma página `html` simples, com apenas um campo de formulário `type="number"`. Quando o usuário clica ele é redirecionado para um url **www.exemplo.com/o_que_ele_digitou_no_formulario**

Objetivo da página: Estamos organizando um evento e queremos que o congressista chegue nessa página, digite o seu cpf, clique no botão e seja redirecionado para uma página www.exemplo.com/cpf. Essa página de destino é protegida por senha e contem os dados do participante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta ai um exemplo de formulário que redireciona para a url ao ser submetido. (No executável do StackOverflow não vai redirecionar)

```js
var baseUrl = 'http://www.exemplo.com.br';
var form = document.querySelector('#congressistaForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 
 window.location.href = [baseUrl, form.cpf.value].join('/');
});
```

```html
<form id="congressistaForm" name="congressistaForm">
  <input type="number" name="cpf" />
  <button>
    Entrar
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solução passa por javascript simples. É só colocar uma função no clique do botão.
Ficam aqui uma opção sem jQuery:

```
var link = "http://www.exemplo.com.br/"+document.getElementById('input_cpf').value;
window.location.href = link;
// ou uma variante com o mesmo efeito
window.location.assign(link);
```

E uma com jQuery:

```
$("#botao_link").on('click', function(){    
    var link = "http://www.exemplo.com.br/"+$('#input_cpf').val();
    $(window.document.location).attr('href',link);
});
```

Se quiser que o cliente abra uma janela nova, pode usar:

```
window.open(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#redirecionar").click(function(){
    var url = "http://www.exemplo.com.br/"+  $("#cpf").val();
    $(location).attr("href", url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="cpf"/>
<input type="button" id="redirecionar" value="Validar"/>
```